# Only allow users see teams that belong to them

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an idea of `teams` in my application. Right now if I go to the show page for a team the ID of the current team is in the params, as it should be. But any user has access to any team, because if I change url to another existing team it will take me there. I want to authorize the url to the current user. How can I achieve this in Phoenix?

I'm using Coherence for authentication currently.

NOTE: I realize I'm not showing any code examples, I would if I had any. To be honest I'm just looking to be pointed in the right direction. I'm completely lost on how to achieve this.

`TEAMS` belong_to `USER`:: `USERS` have_many `TEAMS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have your current user stored in `current_user` you can use:

```
query = from team in Teams, where: team.user_id == ^current_user.id

Repo.get!(query, team_id)
```

Alternatively you can use `Repo.get_by!`:

```
Repo.get_by!(Team, user_id: current_user.id, id: team_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

The relationship is has_many: users and belongs_to team

And then you can check like this

```
 def user_is_member?(team_id, user_id) do
   user = Repo.get(User, user_id)
   team = Repo.get(Team, user.team_id)
   case team.id == team_id do
     true ->
       team
     _ ->
       false
   end
end
```

You can use this for authorization. and for url you can check sub routes for that that might help you.

Comment: Why do you say that @Hauleth? I have my own thoughts but I feel a statement like that deserves a corresponding reason.

Comment: First of all you needlessly do 2 separate requests to DB while one would be more than sufficient. Reducing that to one query would allow you to remove that ugly `case` statement (which should be simple `if` by the way). Your whole function can be written as `Repo.get_by(Team, user_id: user_id, id: team_id) || false`. And if you can live with falsey value instead of `false` per se, then you could even remove that `||` part and have single `Repo.get_by(Team, user_id: user_id, id: team_id)` which returns team if exists and `nil` otherwise.

Comment: And if you want to return 404 if team doesn't exist then you can use `Repo.get_by!(Team, user_id: user_id, id: team_id)` which will throw `Ecto.NoResultsError` which will be handled by [`Plug.Exception`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/1.5.0-rc.0/Plug.Exception.html) (`defimpl` is defined in `ecto_plug`).

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the explanation. Your points make sense to me.